# Android | Compose | Swipe message as Google

Tags: android

Hello android community.
I want to create a swipe toast/message/notification/element as Google chrome download message on Compose.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIldX.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu2oR.jpg

Need compose/kotlin library or any help for android api 26 and high.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these material3 composables to achieve that:

- **Box, Row, Column**
- **TextButton, Text, Icon**
- **SnackbarHost, Snackbar**
- **SwipeToDismiss**

My Implementation:
[image]

Google Chrome:
[image]

First of all, let's create `SwipeableSnackBarBox`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SwipeableSnackBarBox(
    state: SnackbarHostState,
    elevation: Dp,
    shape: Shape,
    alignment: Alignment,
    paddingValues: PaddingValues,
    containerColor: Color,
    contentColor: Color,
    action: @Composable (() -> Unit)?,
    content: @Composable (snackBarData: SnackbarData) -> Unit
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current.density
    val screenWidthInPx = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp * density
    var currentSwipePositionInPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val paddingInPx = paddingValues.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr).value * 2 * density
    val alpha = (screenWidthInPx - currentSwipePositionInPx + paddingInPx) / screenWidthInPx

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues = paddingValues),
        contentAlignment = alignment
    ) {
        SwipeToDismiss(
            state = rememberDismissState(),
            background = {},
            dismissContent = {
                SnackbarHost(
                    hostState = state
                ) { snackBarData ->
                    Snackbar(
                        containerColor = containerColor,
                        contentColor = contentColor,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .alpha(alpha)
                            .clip(shape)
                            .onGloballyPositioned {
                                currentSwipePositionInPx = abs(it.positionInRoot().x)
                            },
                        shape = shape,
                        dismissAction = action,
                        content = { content(snackBarData) }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Now let's use `SwipeableSnackBarBox` to create `SwipeableSnackBar`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SwipeableSnackBar(
    title: String,
    state: SnackbarHostState,
    leadingIcon: ImageVector,
    elevation: Dp = 1.dp,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
    paddingValues: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(elevation),
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
) {
    SwipeableSnackBarBox(
        state = state,
        containerColor = containerColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        shape = shape,
        alignment = alignment,
        paddingValues = paddingValues,
        action = {
            TextButton(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(100.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Open",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    ) { snackBarData ->
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = leadingIcon,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
            )

            Column {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall
                )

                Text(
                    text = snackBarData.visuals.message,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is an example to how to use it**

```kotlin
val snackState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

SwipeableSnackBar(
    state = snackState,
    title = "File Downloaded",
    leadingIcon = Icons.Default.DownloadDone
)

// Simulation
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    delay(3000)
    snackState.showSnackbar(
        message = "(55.27 KB) molo17.com",
        duration = SnackbarDuration.Long
    )
}
```

> Adjust the code according to your specific requirements.

**Hope this helps!**